# Performance difference between SQLITE 3.7.13 and 3.8.0

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, query-performance

Changing SQLITE version has huge performance impact for our queries. We have observed a speedup of over 25 on some queries, although at the same time we observe a slow down of up to 2 on others. **What could be causing this performance difference?**

When comparing execution times, only the execution environment changes. Same hardware, same DB, same query. SQLITE is being used through Perl DBI.

Run time of query 1:

```
 SQLITE 3.8.0(Fedora 19):
 real   0m0.674s
 user   0m0.650s
 sys    0m0.021s

 SQLITE 3.7.13(Debian Wheezy):
 real   0m17.242s
 user   0m17.169s
 sys    0m0.028s
```

Run time of query 2:

```
 SQLITE 3.8.0(Fedora 19):
 real   0m0.303s
 user   0m0.284s
 sys    0m0.017s


 SQLITE 3.7.13(Debian Wheezy):
 real   0m0.168s
 user   0m0.160s
 sys    0m0.007s
```

Not sure if it is useful, but some parameters used to tune the DB:

```
 PRAGMA synchronous = OFF
 PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF
 PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE
 PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY
 PRAGMA PAGE_SIZE = 4096
 PRAGMA cache_size = 125000
```

Comment: This is the [next generation query planner](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner-ng.html).

Comment: @CL. Can you put your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Thanks to the help of @CL., I went to the next generation query planner page that mentioned low-quality index as being "one where there are more than 10 or 20 rows in the table that have the same value". I had one index for a table containing repeated foreign keys. Dropping the index fixed the issue. Now both run around 0.5 seconds.

Comment: I'm too lazy to [provide context for the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). But your own comment would be suitable as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @CL., I went to the [next generation query planner](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner-ng.html) page that mentioned low-quality index as being "one where there are more than 10 or 20 rows in the table that have the same value". I had one index for a table containing only repeated foreign keys. Dropping the index fixed the issue.